# C# Date Format Conversion Error

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

This is my code.

```
        dateString = "6/29/2014";
        format = "yy-mm-dd";
        try
        {
            result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} converts to {1}.", dateString, result.ToString());
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is not in the correct format.", dateString);
        }
```

I want to convert my date 6/29/2014 to 2014-06-29 but i am getting an error that date is not in a correct format . What am i missing here?

Comment: Do you mean "yyyy-mm-dd"?

Comment: yes even i have tried this yyy-mm-dd but i am getting a same error

Comment: Your sample does not make much sense - why do you expect `"6/29/2014"` to (exactly) mach `"yy-mm-dd"` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your format string doesn't match the input, and you didn't specify an output format.

```
var dateString = "6/29/2014";
var format = "M/dd/yyyy";  // adjusted format to match input

try
{
    var result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);

    Console.WriteLine("{0} converts to {1}.",
        dateString, result.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));  // specify output format
}
catch (FormatException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is not in the correct format.", dateString);
}
```

Output:

> 6/29/2014 converts to 2014-06-29.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first parse the date, then to-string it.

```
var asDate = DateTime.Parse(dateString);
var result = asDate.ToString("yy-MM-dd");
```

Also note that `"mm"` in .NET gives you minutes. You need to use `"MM"` for month.

Comment: i am getting this error 'System.DateTime' does not contain a definition for 'Format'

Comment: Yep, I goofed that method call. It should be `DateTime.Parse(dateString)`

Answer (score 1):

Couple things.

You want to pass in the format you're coming FROM to make it a date object. The "conversion" you're looking for comes out the other end. Also, you're not passing in `MM/dd/yy`, that date string is actually `M/dd/yyyy` as it doesn't include the leading zero in the month, and it's a 4-digit year.

Here's a working example.

```
string dateString = "6/29/2014";
string format = "M/dd/yyyy";
try
{
    DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    Console.WriteLine("{0} converts to {1}.", dateString, result.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
}
catch (FormatException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is not in the correct format.", dateString);
}
```

Note that I'm passing the new format into the `ToString` function.